# Add html based off select value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to insert some HTML based off a select value, I plan to have 12 values then have different html inserted based off what each value is. I have done this before and even using the code from before with slight changes to it specific to the code I am working with today.

My HTML code is:

```
    {% extends '../../layouts/appDashboard.html' %}

{% block title %}{{title}}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid container-max">
      <div><br><br></div>

        <div class="box box-warning box-solid">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
              <h3 class="box-title">Create Model</h3>
              <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body no-padding">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-8">
                    <!-- Content here --> 
                    <div class="container">
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
                      <form role="form-inline"action="/dashboard/it/model/new" method="POST">
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="templateName" class="control-label">Template Name</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Asset Template Name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="manufacturer" class="control-label">Manufacturer</label>
                                <select class="form-control selectpicker" title="Manufacturer" name="manufacturer" data-live-search="true">
                                  <option value="cisco">Cisco</option>
                                  <option value="other">Other</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="model" class="control-label">Model Name</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="model" placeholder="Model Name">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="type" class="control-label">Type</label>
                                <select class="form-control selectpicker" title="Type of Asset" name="type" data-live-search="true" id="type" onchange="typePicker()">
                                  <option value="aps">Access Point</option>
                                  <option value="Cable">Cable</option>
                                  <option value="Desktop">Desktop</option>
                                  <option value="Laptop">Laptop</option>
                                  <option value="Desk Phone">Desk Phone</option>
                                  <option value="Mobile Phone">Mobile Phone</option>
                                  <option value="Monitor">Monitor</option>
                                  <option value="Printer">Printer</option>
                                  <option value="Projector">Projector</option>
                                  <option value="Router">Router</option>
                                  <option value="Switch">Switch</option>
                                  <option value="Tablet">Tablet</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group" id="typeInputs">

                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="asset number">Asset Number</label>
                              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="assetNumber" placeholder="Asset Number">
                            </div>            <!-- Asset Number -->

                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="notes">Notes</label>
                              <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="notes" placeholder="Notes.."></textarea>
                            </div>            <!-- Notes -->

                            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                              <label for="">User Assignable</label><br>
                              <label class="btn btn-primary">
                                <input type="radio" name="signout" id="option1"> Yes
                              </label>
                              <label class="btn btn-primary">
                                <input type="radio" name="signout" id="option2"> No
                              </label>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                      <!-- /.box-body -->
                      <div class="box-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col -->
              </div>
              <!-- /.row -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
        </div>
             <!--/.box-body -->
        </div>  



    {% include "../../partials/flash.html" %}


  </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Then my JS code is:

```
function typePicker(){
    var sel=document.getElementById("type");
    var typeInputs=document.getElementById("typeInputs");
    var aps = '<div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="ipaddress" id="ipaddress" placeholder="IP Address"></div>            <!-- IP Address --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="mac-address" id="mac-address" placeholder="MAC Address"></div><!-- MAC Address --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="range" id="range" placeholder="Range in M"></div><!-- Range --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="textbox-n form-control" name="bands" id="bands" placeholder="Bands" ></div><!-- Bands --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="channels" id="channels" placeholder="Channel(s)"></div><!-- Channels --><div class="form-group"><input placeholder="Date Bought" class="textbox-n form-control" type="text" onfocus="(this.type="date")" onblur="(this.type="text")" id="date-bought" name="dateBought"></div><!-- Date Bought --><div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons"><label for="">PoE</label><br><label class="btn btn-primary"><input type="radio" name="poe" id="option1"> Yes</label><label class="btn btn-primary"><input type="radio" name="poe" id="option2"> No</label></div>  <br><br><!-- PoE --><div class="form-group"><input placeholder="Warranty Expiration Date" class="textbox-n form-control" type="text" onfocus="(this.type="date")" onblur="(this.type="text")" id="warranty-date" name="warrantyDate"></div><!-- Warranty Date --><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control"  id="location" placeholder="Location"></div><!-- Location --></div>';

    if(sel.value=="aps"){
        typeInputs.innerHTML=aps;
    }

    if(sel.value!="other"){
        var child = document.getElementById("typeInputs");
        child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
    }
}
```

I know I messed up the HTML in the JS code but I can't even get any to work. Reason I included the full html I need inserted is I am hoping someone knows a better way of coding this so that I don't have un-needed divs and such.

If I am missing any code or details just ask, I will be watching this question closely until I get it to work.

I would also like to have the html disappear change when the user selects another value that way only the html for that value actually shows.

Comment: Why would you have all that HTML in your JS? Have you tried using javascript/jQuery events?

Comment: @VTodorov I have no clue what you mean. I am a fairly novice developer(/hobbyist I guess), so I am not familiar with many things past what I have seen in the courses and posts on here and /r/learnprogramming both of which I have learned a lot from.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the whole HTML document you are using

Comment: @VTodorov I have gone ahead and added the whole HTML file. The template engine is swig since I am using a Node.js backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good practice will be to use events.

Pure JS:

```
var foo = document.getElementById("type");   
foo.addEventListener("change",function(){
    ...
    Do whatever
    ...

});
```

Using jQuery:

```
$('#type').change(function(){
    ....
    Do whatever
    ....
})
```

Comment: Umm it does work.. If you are using plain HTML then no, but if you are using Node.js, Express and swig or ejs it does. My method is working but I have noted your suggestion and will do it that way going forward. Just too lazy to go back and rewrite the code. I will eventually though.

Comment: So I would still need my `var` declarations inside the foo.addEventListener right? Then my if statements would follow that.